# Disable jQuery function on window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I have some jQuery that needs to activate depending on the window size.

The current code I have does trigger correctly when the page is loaded, but if I resize the window the jQuery does not enable or disable according to the size of the screen

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var width = $(window).width();
if ((width < 980)) {
    $( '.navigation > ul > li > a' ).click(function() {
        if($(this).next('ul').is(':visible')){
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $( '.navigation > ul > li > ul' ).slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
    $( '.navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a' ).click(function() {
        if($(this).next("ul").is(":visible")){
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $( '.navigation > ul > li > ul > li > ul' ).slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
    $( '.menu-link' ).click(function() {
        if($(this).next("div").is(':visible')){
            $(this).next("div").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $( '.navigation' ).slideUp(400);
            $(this).next('div').slideToggle(400);
        } 
    });

} 
});
```

Effectively what I need is for the jQuery to trigger under a screen size of 980px and disable over that figure.

As an extra googly I need to make sure that any expanded elements are able to close or are closed when the page size exceeds 980px as over this size the usual CSS media queries take effect on hover.

An earlier version of my code was able to take into account of a dynamic window size, but left the expanded items open and unable to close since the jQuery no longer functioned.

In case it helps here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/untitledgraphic/hEtTg/)

Comment: You don't need to use two parenthesis in if.

Comment: True, force of habit on my part. I've made an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `window.onresize` method.

**EDITED CODE**

```
// flag to check that events doesn't bind twice
var isNavigationEventsEnable = false;

// enable events
var enableNavigationEvents = function () {
    $(".navigation > ul > li > a").on('click.screen-lt-980', function () {
        if ($(this).next("ul").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".navigation > ul > li > ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
    $(".navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a").on('click.screen-lt-980', function () {
        if ($(this).next("ul").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".navigation > ul > li > ul > li > ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
    $(".menu-link").on('click.screen-lt-980', function () {
        if ($(this).next("div").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next("div").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".navigation").slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("div").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
}

// disable events
var disableNavigatioEvents = function () {
    $(".navigation > ul > li > a").off('click.screen-lt-980');
    $(".navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a").off('click.screen-lt-980');
    $(".menu-link").off('click.screen-lt-980');
}

// call this method on window resize
var redesignScreen = function () {
    //function (e) { // comment this line
        var width = $(window).width();
        if ((width < 980)) {
            if (!isNavigationEventsEnable) {
                isNavigationEventsEnable = true;
                enableNavigationEvents();
            }
        } else {
            isNavigationEventsEnable = false;
            disableNavigatioEvents();
        }
    //} // comment this line
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // attach onresize function
    window.onresize = redesignScreen;

    // calling redesignScreen initially
    redesignScreen();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hEtTg/2/

**WITH FORCE CLOSE**

```
// flag to check on that events doesn't bind twice
var isNavigationEventsEnable = false;

// enable events
var enableNavigationEvents = function () {
    $(".navigation > ul > li > a").on('click.screen-lt-980', function (e, data) {
        data = (typeof data == 'undefined') ? {} : data;
        if ($(this).next("ul").is(":visible") || data.forceClose) {
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".navigation > ul > li > ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
    $(".navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a").on('click.screen-lt-980', function (e, data) {
        data = (typeof data == 'undefined') ? {} : data;
        if ($(this).next("ul").is(":visible") || data.forceClose) {
            $(this).next("ul").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".navigation > ul > li > ul > li > ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("ul").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
    $(".menu-link").on('click.screen-lt-980', function (e, data) {
        data = (typeof data == 'undefined') ? {} : data;
        if ($(this).next("div").is(":visible") || data.forceClose) {
            $(this).next("div").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $(".navigation").slideUp(400);
            $(this).next("div").slideToggle(400);
        }
    });
}

// disable events
var disableNavigatioEvents = function () {
    $(".navigation > ul > li > a").trigger('click', [{
        forceClose: true
    }]);
    $(".navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a").trigger('click', [{
        forceClose: true
    }]);
    $(".menu-link").trigger('click', [{
        forceClose: true
    }]);

    $(".navigation > ul > li > a").off('click.screen-lt-980');
    $(".navigation > ul > li > ul > li > a").off('click.screen-lt-980');
    $(".menu-link").off('click.screen-lt-980');
}

// call this method on window resize
var redesignScreen = function () {
    // function (e) { // comment this line
    var width = $(window).width();
    if ((width < 980)) {
        if (!isNavigationEventsEnable) {
            isNavigationEventsEnable = true;
            enableNavigationEvents();
        }
    } else {
        isNavigationEventsEnable = false;
        disableNavigatioEvents();
    }
    //  } // comment this line
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // attach onresize function
    window.onresize = redesignScreen;

    // calling redesignScreen initially
    redesignScreen();
});
```

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hEtTg/3/

Hopes it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't quite work. 
The jQuery is not disabled above 980px and if the window is resized to below that amount, the navigation slides down then back up. Also if you then refresh below 980px nothing functions

Comment: what do you mean by disabling jquery? If your screen size is more than 980px, you need to rwmove jquery. And if you do so, then all events which you bind through jquery will not work.

Comment: Ah, sorry I din't mean disabling jQuery, that would be very wrong. I meant just this code so that above a certain width it stops functioning and below it starts. This is important for tablet devices where the screen size alternates dependent on their orientation, and that on a desktop  where the hover state becomes important the slide effect becomes a hinderance to the user.

Comment: Hi Mohit
That is great in that it gets disabled above 980px, but its also not functioning below 980px. This Fiddle shows what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/untitledgraphic/hEtTg/1/

Comment: @CraigCooper: I mistakenly forgot to comment a line which causing an error. Have a look at the edited code with jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi Mohit, Thats so close, but there's an issue that if an sub menu is open in tablet view, and you resize to desktop then then it stays open and there's no way of closing it. Is there a way of collapsing all open items?

Comment: Oh yes, I got confused and looked at the link to your fiddle.

That does make it close, quite nicely too, but it got a bit carried away and closed entire menu making it disappear.

However  by removing the following code this problem is solved

    $(".menu-link").trigger('click', [{
        forceClose: true
    }]);


Great work Mohit, and thank you very much.